# What is wrong with my clutch

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, kia, rio

So I drive a 2015 Kia rio 1.2 manual.

So my car since I bought it has a very soft clutch that only balances the car for takeoff if i lift it to where it almost switches off the car before i can drive off.
And in heavy traffic when i pull of with he clutch after 15 min the car tends to shake.

So today I serviced my car and when I drove home about 25km from the dealership I was driving in heavy traffic and my car started giving the shakes halfway home.

Then when i was about halfway my clutch started coming back up slowely when i release it and then at one point it stayed down and then it kick to halfway after i change gear then it kick up to full release on its own and my car delayed changing gears. When I reached the traffic lights my car did not want to go into gear 1 and drive off and then i had to wait for tow truck. My car then did not want to start and i could not press the clutch as it was stuck. After a while the clutch was pressable again but my car does not start.
I did not smell anything burning and there was no strange smells in my car engine.
I do not know if i burnt my clutch or it wore out.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!